# Table 'login' does not exists in database

Tags: python, django, djongo

I don't know why i am getting this problem now.It was working fine before
Note: I use djongo (Mongodb) for database

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
        )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    class Meta:
        db_table = "login"
```

Edit:Django Shell Output

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 03, 2020 - 10:55:21
Django version 2.2.11, using settings 'server.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /api/signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\Umar\Project\Backend\server\accounts\views.py", line 26, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\Umar\Project\Backend\server\accounts\serializers.py", line 38, in create
    user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\Umar\Project\Backend\server\accounts\models.py", line 25, in create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 66, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 740, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 777, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 907, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1375, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 48, in execute
    self.result = Result(
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 753, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 824, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 959, in _insert
    self._query = InsertQuery(self, self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 351, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 439, in parse
    tok_id = self._table(2)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 358, in _table
    raise MigrationError(f'Table {collection} does not exist in database')
djongo.sql2mongo.MigrationError: Table login does not exist in database
[03/May/2020 10:55:42] "POST /api/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 205347
```

Edit 2:Migrations Code

```
  operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='User',
            fields=[
                ('password', models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name='password')),
                ('last_login', models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='last login')),
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('email', models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, verbose_name='email address')),
                ('is_active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('is_staff', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('is_superuser', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserProfile',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
                ('first_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('last_name', models.CharField(max_length=50)),
                ('phone_number', models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)),
                ('age', models.PositiveIntegerField()),
                ('gender', models.CharField(choices=[('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female')], max_length=1)),
                ('user', models.OneToOneField(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='profile', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ],
        ),
    ]
```

Update 3:New Django Shell Output

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
May 03, 2020 - 11:24:59
Django version 2.2.11, using settings 'server.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Bad Request: /api/signup/
[03/May/2020 11:25:02] "POST /api/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 400 9699
Internal Server Error: /api/signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\Umar\Project\Backend\server\accounts\views.py", line 26, in post
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 212, in save
    self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\Desktop\Umar\Project\Backend\server\accounts\serializers.py", line 39, in create
    UserProfile.objects.create(
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 740, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 777, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 907, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1375, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 48, in execute
    self.result = Result(
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 753, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 824, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 959, in _insert
    self._query = InsertQuery(self, self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 351, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 439, in parse
    tok_id = self._table(2)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 358, in _table
    raise MigrationError(f'Table {collection} does not exist in database')
djongo.sql2mongo.MigrationError: Table accounts_userprofile does not exist in database
[03/May/2020 11:25:10] "POST /api/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 204612
```

Models:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, email, password=None):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users Must Have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        """
        Create and return a `User` with superuser (admin) permissions.
        """
        if password is None:
            raise TypeError('Superusers must have a password.')

        user = self.create_user(email, password)
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save()

        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True
        )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    # Tells Django that the UserManager class defined above should manage
    # objects of this type.
    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class UserProfile(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='profile')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
```

Update 5: Mongodb Shell ,i pulled out the db names

```
MongoDB server version: 4.2.6
MongoDB Enterprise Accounts-shard-0:PRIMARY> show dbs
accounts              0.000GB
accounts_userprofile  0.000GB
admin                 0.000GB
local                 3.731GB
login                 0.000GB
```

I deleted and recreated migrations each time after every update.

Update 6: I told you,i use djongo so db outputs are already in the django shell but here,i post it again :) This is all i have in my hand

```
File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 422, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 740, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 777, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 870, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 907, in _do_insert
    return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1186, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1375, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\cursor.py", line 48, in execute
    self.result = Result(
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 753, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 824, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 959, in _insert
    self._query = InsertQuery(self, self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 351, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 439, in parse
    tok_id = self._table(2)
  File "C:\Users\Umar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 358, in _table
    raise MigrationError(f'Table {collection} does not exist in database')
djongo.sql2mongo.MigrationError: Table accounts_userprofile does not exist in database
[03/May/2020 11:25:10] "POST /api/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 500 204612
```

fadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfadsfads

Comment: What happens when you connect via Django Shell.  Please provide output for User.objects.all() on django shell

Comment: @Mahori i posted the django shell output

Comment: Can you run migration and try again.

Comment: Did it,but now a new problem "Table accounts_userprofile does not exist in database"

Comment: Okie. Clearly you need to create migrations and run migrations. The absence of table, even though it was there earlier could be due to many reasons - was it over docker without persistent volument? connecting to a different version? actually got erased etc.

Comment: I deleted migrations before due to previous problems.They are solved but this thing exists.Let me try it

Comment: But the thing is that i have migrations folder

Comment: @Mahori i also put the migrations code for you.Check it out!

Comment: Migrations look fine. Can you provide otuput from django shell.. you can enter shell using python manage.py shell . Here please imporrt the User and UserProfile models from necessary packages and provide output.

Comment: @Mahori check it out,i posted them on Update 3 Note:Don't mind the 400 output,it was just a test that i did.

Comment: Not this, the DB shell. Where you will access the DB and pull the data. What you provided is debug log from shell.

Comment: "Can you provide output from django shell.. " You told me django shell ,but no problem . I provided the db output too. I worked fine with this database before,i had this problem just today.Database is based on djongo(mongodb + django),it has its outputs in django shell too

Comment: Umar, sorry about the confusion earlier. I meant DB shell. can you print output for find() on the login collection? What you see there.

Comment: @Mahori No problem,i posted Update 6. Check it out!

Comment: @Mahori i guess you did not found any solution.I will try to open a new database and update you with the news.

Comment: @Mahori i solved the problem.I deleted&recreated the database and moved the project to somewhere else.It works fine.Post your first comment so i can give you a green tick for your work :) Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Haha.. Glad you worked it out! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the errors posted by OP, it's likely that somehow DB got deleted or probably a version difference since last migrations.

A good idea would be to create migrations and run migrations on perhaps a fresh DB instance.